# How to set Audible notifications in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I will be developing an android app in PhoneGap soon, the app will feature a reminder mechanism that will display a popup/push notification at certain dates and time intervals set by the user. The notifications will be audible. I just wanted to know, is it possible in PhoneGap, if so how can I accomplish it. I think Appcelerator supports it through its Calendar library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification plugin on Android can play a sound at a given time:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification